# multilevel piechart dc.js

Tags: pie-chart, dc.js

I am trying to create a pieChart using dc.js (Using its Cross-Filter Functionality). I have found something similar to [this](http://codepen.io/pankajkumar005/pen/RPOeNV?editors=%5C%601111%5C%60) but it is using d3.js.
Does anybody know how to do this?
Thanks!

```
.
```

Comment: (Why all the downvotes today?) What you are looking for is usually called a "sunburst chart." [There is a PR you can try](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/907) but it needs working tests to be merged into dc.js proper. You should be able to copy it into your copy of dc.js.

Comment: thank you very much for this information!